# Facebook For Wordpress configuration issue

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am trying to configure the plugin "Facebook For Wordpress", but it's not working. I followed the instructions on the [plugin page](https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/) and I've also tried [this userguide](http://fbwordpress.com/fbwordpress.pdf), but when I try to post on facebook with the plugin I alway have the following error :

```
Failed posting to your Facebook Timeline. Error: null
```

I can't submit my open graph because I can't post on my facebook timeline.

Can you help me?

I am using the plugin version 1.0.2 and the Wordpress version 3.3.1